# Environment variables in a React SharePoint Webpart?

Tags: environment-variables, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I'm trying to add environment variables to a SPO Webpart written in React. The webpart has a dependency on an API and the instance of the API to be used varies depending on the environment. Webpart deployed to IST should use the IST API. Webpart deployed to UAT should use the UAT instance of the API.

In regular app development this is straightforward. But not for React Webparts.

I've gone through and tried the following:

[Using .env files in SharePoint Framework development](https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2020/03/05/using-env-files-in-sharepoint-framework-development/)

[How To Handle Env Variable Using DefinePlugin In SPFx Solutions](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-handle-env-variable-using-defineplugin-in-spfx-solutions/)

[Read and manipulate SPFx configuration values in your code like a boss](https://spblog.net/post/2018/06/24/Read-and-manipulate-SPFx-configuration-values-in-your-code-like-a-boss)

[Using environment variables in React](https://trekinbami.medium.com/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

[SPFx environment variable for CI / CD for SharePoint on-premise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299714/spfx-environment-variable-for-ci-cd-for-sharepoint-on-premise)

**Does anyone have a working solution?**